# TU for Teaching Unit in a transcript?

Tags: word-usage

I am currently in the process of translating some transcripts in English. In France, teaching is organized around UE, standing for "Unité d'Enseignements". In English, that would simply stands for Teaching Unit. However, I wonder if the term TU appears commonly on English academic transcripts ?

Example: TU1.04 Social media and communication

Edit: a UE stands almost literally for Teaching Unit (or TU). It's a block of courses, and you have lot of them, e.g. TU1.01 European politics TU1.02 USA politics TU1.05 Politics and economy.

Comment: What does TU1.04 mean?  Is it the numerical designation of the class?  In many colleges/universities classes are numbered with the subject as the prefix, for example: "MAT104 Linear Algebra and Multivariate Calculus."  The class might be worth 4 "units" (or 2, or 8, or 6, or whatever each school's system requires) that is counted towards graduation.

Comment: @Andrew It basically means Teaching Unit 1.04 . Would it be very unclear to you if you saw that on a transcript ?

Comment: @Andrew Have you heard it as being a standard practice in some english transcripts delivering institutions or countries ?

Comment: Most often the prefix for a course is related to the department where the course is taught: MAT - math, LIT - literature, PSY - psychology. It sounds like your "TU" is a general prefix no matter which department is teaching it.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant as someone from the USA, I've never heard of it before, and it doesn't seem to impart any useful information.  As Peter and I pointed out, college courses have designations that relate to their department, so just by looking at a course called ENG105 I know it's an English (or possibly an Engineering) class.  Some schools will use three-letter designations, some four-letter, and maybe even smaller schools will use two-letter designations.  But TU1.04 doesn't tell me anything other than the class is sub-section 4 under the general "1.xx" classification.

Comment: I second Andrew; I'm from the USA, I have spent a lot of time around colleges, and I have never heard "teaching unit" or "TU" used.  It sounds like a UE is a group or selection of courses?

Comment: Yes a UE stands almost literaly for Teaching Unit (or TU). It's a block of courses, and you have lot of them, e.g. TU1.01 European politics TU1.02 USA politics TU1.05 Politics and economy . But the interesting thing that you pointed out is that, for USA, every course begin with its prefix, such as ECO204. Is there also the course name beside, like ECO24 USA Economy ?

Comment: Does the course catalog include a key that lists the abbreviations and meanings? Beyond that, I think these usages are unique to systems identifying academic courses, and are not generally used. It might be better to ask your specific question (whether xxx is used) on [*Acadamia SE*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Andrew My school used 2 letter department codes. Now I feel inferior. :-(

Comment: @Jay well, gee, sorry.  I went to a school that's literally its own zip code, so I guess I was judging based on that.  It's not necessarily a good thing to be that big, of course.

Comment: It's not true that "for USA, every course begin with its prefix." There is no required standard by which all institutions identify courses. Many do use such prefixes, but some don't. For example, at Evergreen St. College, "Mathematics in Geology" is identified as **AACBYO.** There is no organization or governmental body tasked with organizing such things in the U.S. Any college or university can do whatever they wish.

Comment: @Andrew A friend of mine went to a college that had its own zip code. And they made all room numbers on campus unique, i.e. if there was a room 1242 say in one building, that would be the only room 1242 on campus. So theoretically, a sufficient address to send him a letter would have been, "Chris, Room 1242, 91001". Never did try it.

Answer (score 2):

In America, most colleges and universities do not use that type of prefix, and it will most likely not be immediately understandable to the average reader. Usually courses are grouped by department of study (often abbreviated with a prefix) and then given a numeric code (usually based on the year it's normally taken in [freshman through senior], the availability of the course in spring and fall semesters, and one or two other things). For example, I took CS211, "Algorithms and Data Structures", in my first year of college. It was in the Computer Science department, a sophomore-level class, and available only in the fall as I recall.

In Britain, there appears to be a similar structure, perhaps starting with the level (4-7), then a letter code, then a numeric code. King's College London, for example, has first-year classes like 4AAEA001 (Introducing Literary Theories) and 4AAE0205 (Classical and Biblical Contexts).

Courses also have a certain number of *credit hours* or *units* associated with them, usually 1-4. These don't normally have any abbreviation, since "credit" and "unit" are both pretty short.

Of course, since colleges are free to organize their course catalog any way they feel like, these are not hard-and-fast rules, just a general set of conventions. But very few colleges in the English-speaking world would, I think, use a single prefix for every class or course in their catalog. It's just not considered necessary to specify anything like that.

Comment: As a footnote, sometimes a block of related courses can be referred to as a _sequence_.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as an American: I don't think I've ever heard the term "Teaching Unit", nor would the acronym "TU" be generally recognized.

It sounds like you're inventing the acronym "TU" by translating a French term to English and then making an acronym from the English words. I think in general the chance that that would result in an acronym that would be recognized by English-speakers is small. For starters, there are almost always multiple ways to translate the same group of words. Like you say the French translates to "Teaching Unit", but maybe someone else would say "Education Unit" or "Teaching Element" or some other variation. And English speakers may use very different words for the same idea. I'm still not quite clear what you mean by a "teaching unit" here, but it sounds like it may mean what they called a "course track" in my college. Etc.

If you were writing an article or a book, the thing to do would be to explain the acronym. That is, say, "In France we use a thing we call a 'Unité d'Enseignements', which means 'Teaching Unit'. In this book I will refer to these as TUs ..." etc. (Hopefully or more complete explanation and better worded than that, but that's the idea.)

If you're preparing a transcript or a resume, hmm, that's tougher because they're normally expected to be very abbreviated. I'd probably put it in with the French acronym -- are you saying you use "UE"? -- because at least that's a "real" acronym. Then if someone asks, explain it. They might not care. If a potential employer or a grad school or whatever sees "UE 103.72 Nuclear Physics", they probably don't care what the numbers mean.

Comment: If you saw the term in each and every transcript sheet, before the course denomination (e.g. TU 2.24 Ethics in engineering etc), could you guess it, at least ?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant I presume one could guess that it was something to do with education, but what? I might guess that it means something like "course identifier". Or I might wonder if it identifies the school he went to, or the department and all his classes are from the same department. Depending on the pattern of the numbers I might think it means how many credits the class was worth. Or ... many possible things. It would be hard to guess.